# Create canonical urls in rails /:category/:product/:item/ in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How can one create a url in this form `/:category/:product/:item/` from a `link_to` method.

I have tried this:

```
parameters: {category: @category, product: @product, item: @item}

= link_to "list", url_for(controller: "items", action: "list", params: parameters), 
  class: "button radius #{ additional_classes }", rel: "canonical"
```

But it gives me this url: `/list?product=a&category=b&item=c`. I am really interested in getting the other format

PS: I am using slim but the way not `HTML`

Comment: Can you please show your route file how you have used resource?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories, path: "" do
   resources :product, path: "" do
     resources :item, path: ""
   end
end
```

This will create the following url: `url.com/:category_id/:product_id/:id`

You'll be able to use the following `link_to` helper:

```
<%= link_to @item.title, [@category, @product, @item] %>
```

--

Although it should work, it's [not recommended](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting):

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

Therefore, you may wish to refactor your routes/infrastructure so that you're calling `item_id` above all -- `product` & `categories` acting as index methods:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories, path: "", only: :index
resources :products, only: :index do
   resources :items
end
```

This would allow you to to call `<%= link_to "Products", products_path %>` to get a list of products, and then `<%= link_to @item.id, products_item_path(@product, @item) %>` to get a specific item.

---

You may also wish to look at [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

This will do nothing to your routes (it resides in your model) -- it basically allows you to use [`slug`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) to identify your resources (rather than `id`'s).

I can update the answer if you'd like to know more about it; basically it will allow you to have urls like:

```
url.com/:category_id/:product_id/:item
url.com/category-name/product-name/item-name
```

---

**Friendly ID**

Friendly ID just replaces the `:id` parameter of your routes / `find` methods with the `slug` param. To set up `friendly_id`, you basically need to add a `slug` attribute to your model (with a migration), and then include the `FriendlyID` class on the model itself.

Here's how do you'd set it up:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :categories, path: "" do
  resources :subcategories, path: "" do
    resources :products, path: "" # => http://url.com/:category_id/:subcategory_id/:product_id
  end
end
```

It must be noted that nesting the resourceful routes that deeply is [not recommended](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting) (I'll leave it to demonstrate what to do).

Rails will take the above and create a route helper such as `category_subcategory_product_path(:category, :subcategory, :product)`.

By passing the *objects* for each of those values, "naked" Rails will just infer the `id` from them. `FriendlyID` (if set up correctly) should replace the `id` with the `slug` column in all of those models.

You need to set it up like the following:

```
# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:finders, :slugged]
end

# app/models/subcategory.rb
class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:finders, :slugged]
end

# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:finders, :slugged]
end
```

This - if you migrate each of those models to include a `slug` column - will allow Rails to populate the route helper with the `slug` object. Of course, that doesn't matter if you just use the naked values anyway:

```
category_subcategory_product_path(@category.slug, @subcat.slug, @product.slug)
```

The trick is to handle the slug in the controller.

You can pass any value you want through the route helpers (there is no validation). The difference lies in how you manage the passed data in the controllers:

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product = Product.find params[:id] #-> FriendlyID will automatically look up the slug if present
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Richard, would it be possible to update your answer regarding the friendly_id part? It's exactly what I need - a url like this: url.com/category/subcategory/product-name - and I can't yet figure out how to do that.

Comment: Sure, let me do that

Comment: Dear Richard, I'm still struggling with this problem. Would be really kind of you if you could help me and others out.

Comment: Sorry, yes of course - I completely forgot! I'll do it in a second

Comment: Okay I updated but I am tired - I will redo it tomorrow -- let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already started to implement this functionality on my own via deep nesting, but thought there is another way, because initially you did not recommend it. However in your update you seem to use just this approach. I will continue implementation using your updated answer. Will come back later if there are any troubles. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi again. Your solution works just fine, thanks again for updating the post. It's just... a bit odd to work with, since, for example:
`-@categories.each do |category|
 =link_to category.title, category_path(category.slug)`
is handled by the INDEX action (and `categories_path` redirects to "/") instead of SHOW. I understand, that it comes from `path: "/"` option, but nevertheless it's a bit odd.

Comment: If you're using `friendly_id` on the `Category` model, you only need to reference the `category` object (the `slug` is inferred from it): `category_path(category)` or even better `link_to category.title, category`

Comment: Ultimately, the path should be the same resourceful nature as the others - if you post your `repo` url I will take a look and see if I can offer any recommendations

Comment: I changed the paths and it's working fine:
`%h1 Application root

-@categories.each do |category|
 =link_to category.title, category`
However, `link_to category.title, category` still leads to pages#index controller.
My repo url is [here](https://github.com/mohnstrudel/ycms). Please note, that I'm not using Category model in the real app, but instead PageCategory (it's important for my app to have different category models)

Comment: Okay so I looked at the repo and all seems to be in working order. Without me cloning it, the first thing you need to do is check removing `index` from the route definition for `pages_categories`. This will ensure that only show is present. If this works as intended, the issue will be with the routes; if not it will be a problem deeper in the application. If you try it, please get back to me -- if it doesn't work, I'll clone the repo and see what the issue is myself

Comment: Hi, it's still the same. But I'm pretty sure it's because of the `path: ""` in the routes.rb, since without this parameter I have this URL for a specific category `http://localhost:3000/page_categories/second-category`. This loads exactly the expected - `show.html.haml` template, which has only a `hello` output. And here you go - http://take.ms/pIepW

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by doing a merge:

`parameters: {category: @category, product: @product, item: @item}`

`= link_to "list", url_for(controller: "items", action: "list").merge(parameters), 
  class: "button radius #{ additional_classes }", rel: "canonical"`

Answer (score -1):

Try change your routes like this :

```
get '/:category/:product/:item/', 'items#list', :as => 'item_list'
```

So you will get `item_list_path` and you can use it in link like this.

```
= link_to "list", item_list_path(@category, @product, @item)
```

But be sure to pass params in same order as they are in url.